# Проблема с Логин формой (Mysql и php)

Tags: php, mysql, авторизация

Когда пытаюсь залогиниться с введёным паролем, не перенаправляет на другую страницу, хотя пароль правильный. А при попытке зайти без пароля — перенаправляет.

В чём может быть проблема?

Пример кода:

```
if (empty($errors)) { 
    $userQuery = "SELECT * FROM admins" ; 
    $userResult = mysqli_query($connection, $userQuery); 

    while($userRow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($userResult)) { 
        if($userRow["username"] == $_POST["username"] && $userRow["password"] == $_POST["password"]) { 
             $_SESSION["username"] = $_POST["username"]; 
             redirect_to("../public/library.php"); //это Функция
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: у Вас не было одной закрывающей скобки. Это Вы не докопировали код или ее действительно у Вас нет?

Comment: В проекте всё есть

Comment: @pavel замечу, что MySQL умеет гораздо больше, чем `select *` из всей таблицы. вы можете написать `select * from admins where username='pavel'` и он выберет именно нужную запись и вам не понадобится перебирать в цикле всю таблицу

Comment: @pavel Так же стоит привести кусок кода который нормально перенаправляет, что бы увидеть отличия. И самое главное, у вас в коде до указанного куска с проверкой пароля нигде на текущую страницу ничего не выводится ? потому как редирект после вывода хотя бы одного символа невозможен.

Comment: нет не выводится я прописываю это всё до DOCTYPE html

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
if (empty($errors)) { 
    $userQuery = "SELECT * FROM admins WHERE
        username = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["username"]) . "'
        AND password = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["password "]) . "'"; 
    $userResult = mysqli_query($connection, $userQuery); 

    if( mysqli_num_rows($userResult) ) {
        $_SESSION["username"] = $_POST["username"]; 
        redirect_to("../public/library.php");
    }
}
```